# How merge array objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to know if this is possbile

```
arr1 = [{
  text: "John",
  Description: "tall"
}, {
  text: "Dave",
  Description: "short"
}, {
  text: "Christian",
  Description: "medium"
}, {
  text: "Mark",
  Description: "thin"
}]

arr2 = [{
  text2: "Orange",
  Description2: "sweet"
}, {
  text2: "Prunes",
  Description2: "Bitter"
}, {
  text2: "Apple",
  Description2: "sweet"
}]
```

I want to merge the two arrays to look like this

```
arr3 = [{
  text: "John",
  Description: "tall",
  text2: "Orange",
  Description2: "sweet"
}, {
  text: "Dave",
  Description: "short",
  text2: "Prunes",
  Description2: "Bitter"
}, {
  text: "Christian",
  Description: "medium",
  text2: "Apple",
  Description2: "sweet"
}, {
  text: "Mark",
  Description: "thin"
}]
```

I have tried to use concat() but it only puts the merge object at the end of the first array it does not seem to give the output that I want.

Comment: **Yes** It's possible. Iterate over array, get element at the index from both arrays, combine them in single object, add it to the same index in new array. Hint: `Object.assign`.

Comment: you don't *just* want to merge the array, you want to merge the objects that are at each array index.

Comment: What do you want to do if the second array has more elements than the first?

Comment: @nnnnnn it will just be untouched but still be merged in the array object

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple way to do it using a basic loop:

```
var arr3 = [];

for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length || i < arr2.length; i++)
  arr3.push( Object.assign({}, arr1[i], arr2[i]) );
```

The [`Object.assign()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) copies "the values of all enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target object", and returns the new object.

In the code I've shown, the first argument to `Object.assign()` is a new empty object, the second argument is the element in `arr1` at index `i`, and the third argument is the corresponding element in `arr2`. Noting that `Object.assign()` ignores arguments that are undefined, this will work even if `arr1` and `arr2` are different lengths (if `i` is greater than or equal to `arr1.length` then `arr1[i]` will be `undefined`, and same for `arr2`).

(Expand and run this snippet to see it working:)

```js
var arr1 = [{
  text: "John",
  Description: "tall"
}, {
  text: "Dave",
  Description: "short"
}, {
  text: "Christian",
  Description: "medium"
}, {
  text: "Mark",
  Description: "thin"
}];

var arr2 = [{
  text2: "Orange",
  Description2: "sweet"
}, {
  text2: "Prunes",
  Description2: "Bitter"
}, {
  text2: "Apple",
  Description2: "sweet"
}];

var arr3 = [];

for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length || i < arr2.length; i++)
  arr3.push(Object.assign({}, arr1[i], arr2[i]));
console.log(arr3);
```

Answer (score 1):

We'll start off by writing a little utility routine which loops across two arrays, and returns an array of the results of calling some function on each pair of elements, sort of like `Array#map` but working on two input arrays:

```
function map2(a1, a2, fn) {
  const len = Math.max(a1.length, a2.length);
  const result = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    result.push(fn(a1[i], a2[i]);
  }

  return result;
}
```

With this under our belt, the solution is just

```
map2(arr1, arr2, (a1, a2) => Object.assign({}, a1, a2))
```

Note that `Object.assign` will ignore `undefined`, which is the behavior we want here, since this will happen if one array is longer than the other.

#### Extra credit

We can extend our utility to routine to work on any number of input arrays, specified as an array of arrays, with the provided function taking an array of values:

```
function multiMap(arrays, fn) {
  const len = Math.max(...arrays.map(a => a.length));
  const result = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    result.push(fn(arrays.map(a => a[i])));
  }

  return result;
}
```

Then

```
multiMap([arr1, arr2], args => Object.assign({}, ...args)
```